# How to add an additional web part zone to a site home page?

Tags: web-part-zone

I have a site where the home page has the two web parts zone, left and right. I would like to add a third web part zone to the top, that spans across the left and the right web part zone. I'm trying to determine if this should be done with a master page, or just create a new web part page and make that the home page ... or some other way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Nobody explained how to do it in Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quick answer is that if you want all the site pages to have the new zone, then make your change in the master page.  If it is only the home page, then editing a web part page and making it the home page as you suggest is fine.

Comment: Also, if it is the new wiki style home page that is new in 2010, I would recommend the second option (changing the page itself).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a normal webpart page then you can edit the page using SharePoint designer to add the zone.  It's a publishing page, then you have to edit the page layout to add the zone.

Comment: I just created the default site ... so whatever is set as the home page for that?

Comment: You mean a team site?  There isn't a template called default in SP that I am aware of.